# Laravel API: The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD

Tags: php, laravel, rest, post, laravel-passport

I am sending a post request to `http://localhost/projects/webdevlist/public/api/register` and getting the 405 error:

```
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException
The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD.
```

routes\api.php:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
});

Route::post('/register', 'Api\AuthController@register');
```

Api\AuthController.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Api;

use App\User;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class AuthController extends Controller
{
    public function register(Request $request)
    {
        $validatedData = $request->validate([
            'name' => 'required|max:55',
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'password' => 'required|confirmed'
        ]);

        $user = User::create($validatedData);

        $accessToken = $user->createToken('token')->accessToken;

        return response(['user' => $user, 'access_token' => $accessToken]);
    }
}
```

If I remove the form validation then I can do post requests just fine and return a result in postman like this.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Api;

use App\User;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class AuthController extends Controller
{
    public function register(Request $request)
    {
        return response()->json([
            $request->name,
            $request->email,
            $request->password,
        ]);
    }
}
```

But something is wrong with my validation. Why does the validation cause me to no longer be able to accept `POST` requests?

Here is my POST request:
[image]

Comment: Show .blade.php file pls. You use {{ Form::open... }}?

Comment: Hi there, this is an API so I am making the post request through insomnia. I have added a picture. Thanks.

Comment: Adding Accept application/json as a header allowed this to work too

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem with your validation is the `password` field.

Your rule say that it need to be required and **confirmed**, but confirmed against which field?

You need to add a field with name `password_confirmation` your view, if not added yet.

```
 <input type="password" name="password_confirmation" />
```

And then add a new rule for `password_confirmation` field:

```
$validatedData = $request->validate([
    'name' => 'required|max:55',
    'email' => 'required|email',
    'password' => 'required|confirmed',
    'password_confirmation' => 'required'
]);
```

Comment: That's fascinating. I wonder why this would disallow POST requests to this route.

Comment: We need to debug more on the Stack Trace to know why ;)